# How do I make a game for the chromecast

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I want to create a simple game for the Chromecast, where the game is on the TV and the phone is the controller.

I found two possible ways to do this: Google Manager API and Remote Display API, but both seem to be deprecated according to the documentation in these links:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/gaming
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote

What are Googles future plans for developing games (and other non-media-streaming-apps) for the Chromecast?

Is it possible to create a game without the API above? (The game will be a simple quiz game)

Comment: Check the [Build TV games](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/games/), "The television screen presents a number of considerations that may be new to mobile game developers. These areas include its large size, its control scheme, and the fact that all players are viewing it simultaneously."

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out please? I have previously built demos on the v2 sdk, but don't wish to further develop against deprecated code. I guess google have given up with chromecast games?

Comment: @RussTaylor No, I never got an answer. But looking at the documentation for the "Remote display" page in cast dokumentation, It does not state that it is depricated, just that it should not be mixed with "CAF". I will try to develop a game with it and hope google does not remove the feature.

Comment: Hi. Did anyone find a solution please?